# Which is the best interactive map library in react js?

Tags: reactjs

I'm looking for recommendations of an easy library to create an interactive map in react js. The idea is to keep track of incidents in a plantation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check which map suits you using ,

https://react.rocks/tag/Map

They have source code also attached.

You may try https://uber.github.io/react-map-gl/
This is created by Uber.

Answer (score 0):

I advice you to use [react-map-gl](https://github.com/uber/react-map-gl).
Very comfortable and expandable. Well written documentation.